# Redmine in Mandriva Linux -- setting up e-mail notifications

Tags: linux, smtp, redmine

I use BitNami Redmine Stack in Mandriva Linux.
Attempting send e-mail notification leads to the error- message -

```
(503 5.5.1 Error: authentication not enabled )
```

Redmine configuration file configuration.yml:

```
production:
  email_delivery:
     delivery_method: :smtp
     smtp_settings:
       enable_starttls_auto: true
       address: ...ip...
       port: 25
       domain: redmine@....
       authentication: :plain
       user_name: ....
       password: ...
```

What is configured wrong?

I changed the configuration a bit later:

```
 production:
  email_delivery:
     delivery_method: :smtp
     smtp_settings:
       tls: true
       address: ...ip smtp..
       port: 25
       domain: ...
       authentication: :plain
       user_name: ...
       password: ...
```

I added `tls: true` and now the error is -

```
(SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol)
```

There is a documentation - http://wiki.bitnami.org/Applications/BitNami_Redmine
I've added `openssl_verify_mode: 'none'` and removed `tls: true`, then the original error message returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "503 5.5.1" error is from your mail server, saying that it does not have SMTP authentication enabled.  You have configured Redmine to use SMTP authentication, by including these lines:

```
   authentication: :plain
   user_name: ....
   password: ...
```

I believe you can change the ":plain" to ":none" to tell Redmine not to use authentication.  http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/EmailConfiguration

Another alternative is to configure your mail server to require authentication, see for example the following note on where to find that setting in the postfix mail server: http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/9506.

One last alternative, if you have a working local sendmail/mta, is to use that instead of SMTP.  There's an example of this in the first link above.